# Display a div with space between div and trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to display a div when I mouse over a trigger, but I had space between trigger and div. The problem are rebound effect with timeout and the trigger to display none the div not work.

You can check on this link http://jsfiddle.net/pGjXs/

```
<div id="micro-shopping-bag">
    <a href="#todo" class="msb-trigger">Trigger</a>
    <div id="micro-shopping-bag-inner">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, the `<div>` is hidden again two (and a bit) seconds after your mouse leaves the `<a>` element.

Comment: by space do you mean `<br />`?

Comment: @jbabey space between is not `<br />` but the style

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes is disappear when you leave link or the div.

Comment: @Atu so you want the shopping bag div to appear further away from the hover link?

Comment: You need to be much, much clearer about what it is that's happening that isn't what you want, and what it is you actually want to happen. Your code says "Show the div when you mouseover the link. When your mouse leaves the link, hide the div after two seconds." and that is what happens - what do you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mouseenter` may happen before the timeout has executed which leads to the div disapearing even if your mouse enters it. To correct this you should save the `setTimeout` to a variable and call `clearTimeout` when you hit `mouseenter` before you fadeIn.

I think this is what you want given that you didn't gave us much to work with, it just seams to me as a standard behavior.